# Django Rest Framework JWT Auth

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt

I have an issue posting/getting any requests after JWT login. (I am using the [**djangorestframework-jwt**](https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) library) The user succesfully logs in, the app returns the json token but when I use this token for the next requests I get

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),
}
```

**Login View**

```
def post(self, request, format=None):

    if not request.data:
        return Response({'Error': "Please provide username/password"},  status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    username = request.data['username']
    password = request.data['password']

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=username, password=password)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({'Error': "Invalid username/password"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    if user:
        payload = {
            'id': user.id,
            'email': user.email,
            'first_name': user.first_name
        }

        jwt_token = jwt.encode(payload, "SECRET_KEY")  # to be changed

        return Response({'token': jwt_token}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and then every other view contains

```
 authentication_class = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
 permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

I have tested both with postman and curl but I get the same error. Not sure if there is an error with the header format or if there is smth else I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

EDIT: 
I have changed my settings to

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
),
```

but now I get that

```
{
    "detail": "Error decoding signature."
}
```

EDIT: I think the issue is that `jwt_token = jwt.encode(payload, 'SECRET_KEY')` might return a token that is not recognised...if i use the token generated by `obtain_jwt_token` then i can query any endpoint. Could anyone explain this?

EDIT: so I changed to `jwt_token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)` and the settings file contains the `JWT_SECRET_KEY` (when i verify the token i receive after login on jwt, it is indeed the right token with the right payload and secret) but it's still not recognised `"detail": "Invalid signature."`

Comment: @JPG that's the thing, i get the same error when i try to verify it

Comment: The jwt token is encrypted and signed using a secret. When you create a custom token by using jwt.encode and use secret as 'SECRET_KEY' then the same key need to use for decode. Imp. 'SECRET_KEY' is a string. Refer the answer i posted below and add a secret key variable in your settings file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. When authenticating a user I was checking against a custom `user` table that I had created earlier,  which was different from the django's `auth_user` table. I changed django's settings to use my custom users table and then using the token from the authentication worked for the other requests as well.

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.User'`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you encode the JWT by using "SECRET KEY" and decode using another key. The default secret key used by jwt is settings.SECRET_KEY. But when you create a custom jwt token you uses a string as secret "SECRET_KEY". But you use default jwt verification which automatically uses settings.SECRET_KEY. 
So add `'JWT_SECRET_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,` in to your JWT settings and use this key for encode and decode.
Ex:

```
jwt_token = jwt.encode(payload, settings.SECRET_KEY)
```

or you can override the jwt verification and create your own.